# Meaning of rotational invariance breaking and lifting of degeneracy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, perturbation-theory, hydrogen, invariants

The $2p$ level of hydrogenic atoms are $3-$fold degenerate. That is $\psi_{210}$ and $\psi_{21\pm1}$ all have the same energy $E_{n=2}$. And the level $n=2$ as a whole is $4-$fold degenerate, since $2s$ or $\psi_{200}$ also has the energy $E_{n=2}$.

Now consider **Stark effect**: an external electric field, with field strength $\mathcal{E}$, be applied along $z$-direction. As a result of it, using time-independent and degenerate perturbation theory we can see that the two levels $\psi_{21\pm1}$ do not shift in energy, but the other two levels $\psi_{200}$ and $\psi_{210}$ are shifted.
So the degeneracy is "partly" removed.

Now coming to my doubt. Consider the following statement

> The degeneracy is partly removed by the perturbation which picks out a
> particular direction of space so that the rotational invariance of the
> system is destroyed.

Yes the degeneracy is partly lifted since whereas previously there were four sub-levels with the same energy, now after the application of electric field we have three energy values; two with the same energy as before (the $\psi_{21\pm1}$ sub-levels), one (the level $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_{200}-\psi_{210})$) with an increased amount of energy, and another (the level $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_{200}+\psi_{210})$) with a decreased amount of energy.
And yes a particular direction, the $z$-direction is picked out as we have applied the field that way.

But what does the other stuff mean? Why or how *rotational invariance* got destroyed? And how breaking of degeneracy is related with the destruction of rotational invariance?

Comment: I don’t understand why you ask “Why or how rotational invariance got destroyed?” after correctly noting that “a particular direction, the z-direction is picked out as we have applied the field that way”.

Comment: Picking out a particular direction is incompatible with spherical symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rotational invariance / symmetry means that the Hamiltonian of the system remains identical after rotating it. For the Hyrdogen atom Hamiltonian it is clear that it is invariant under rotations, as the kinetic part is $\propto \vec{p}^2$ which is a scalar under rotations, and the potential energy is $\propto 1/r$ which is also a rotational-invariant quantity (the distance of the electron from the nucleus doesn't change when we rotate with the center kept at the nucleus).

This symmetry immediately implies a degeneracy in energy levels. To see this, we consider how rotations are done in QM, by a unitary operator which we will label $R(\theta, \hat{n})$ with $\hat{n}$ the unit vector about which we rotate and $\theta$ the rotation angle. This operator is explicitly given by $R(\theta, \hat{n})=\exp(-i\theta \vec{L}\cdot\hat{n}/\hbar)$ with $\vec{L}$ here are the angular momentum operators. So if rotations doesn't change the Hamiltonian, it means that $R H R^{\dagger} = H$ for all $R$, or alternatively $[ R, H ] = 0$ which we can translate to $[L_i, H]=0$ for all $L_i$. We also know from classical mechanics that a rotationally invariant system means that angular momentum is conserved, and we just got that result quantum mechanically. This means that the angular momentum ladder operators $L_{\pm}$ also commute with $H$, which means that states with different values of $m$ have the same energy. Because if $H|n,l,m \rangle = E|n,l,m\rangle$ with some value of $E$ then $H|n,l,m\pm 1 \rangle = H c_{n,l,m}L_{\pm}|n,l,m\rangle =  c_{n,l,m}L_{\pm} H |n,l,m \rangle = E |n,l,m\pm 1\rangle$ with the same energy (where $c_{n,l,m}$ is just a normalization factor), and the crucial part is the fact that we could commute the operations of $H$ and $L_{\pm}$.

So we have seen that **any** Hamiltonian which is rotational symmetric has (1) angular momentum as a good quantum number and (2) at least $2L+1$ degeneracy of any state with quantum number $L$, as different values of $m$ don't matter. For the hydrogen atom Hamiltonian we have an extra degeneracy as it turns out that different values of $L$ also don't matter, but this is a topic for another day.

Applying an external field in a specific direction breaks the rotational symmetry, as a preferred direction is not invariant under rotations. Adding a term like $(-Ez)$ to the Hamiltonian means that if we rotate about the $y$ axis this might turn into $(-Ex)$ for example. So this clearly breaks the symmetry $R H R^{\dagger} \neq H$. As the symmetry is broken we can no longer expect the full degeneracy that this symmetry entailed, and indeed we see that some of the degeneracy is lifted.